# PHP - how to detect encoding?

Tags: php, regex, encoding, character-encoding

I'm using Amazon's API to obtain the description of books. The API returns XML responses and the description is marked up (with HTML) very poorly. To deal with this poorly marked up description, which oftentimes breaks the layout of my site, I'm trying to use HTML Tidy to "clean it up."

In order to prevent "weird" characters from being displayed on my web page, I think I need to tell Tidy what the input encoding is and what the desired output encoding is. I know I want the output to be UTF8. However, I'm not sure how to determine the encoding of the input (Amazon's book description).

I've tried something like this:

```
mb_detect_encoding($amazon_description);
```

It's helped, but I'm still occasionally getting weird characters (a black diamond with a question mark in it: �). My guess is that I'm not detecting the encoding properly.

Any suggestions what I need to do?

**EDIT:**

This is my current solution:

```
$sanitized_amazon_markup = preg_replace('/[^\w`~!@#$%^&*()-=_+[\]{}|;\':",.\/<>? ]/', '', $sanitized_amazon_markup);
```

I'm not sure about this as this may delete stuff that I should be keeping.

Comment: It could be that if they're sloppy with their HTML, they're sloppy with their character encoding.

Comment: It appears to me that Amazon is not the source of the book descriptions. Sometimes the descriptions are marked up well. Sometimes it's got divs and spans with various classes. Sometimes it seems like the descriptions come from Word (with its proprietary mark up).

Comment: automatically detecting character encoding is more or less impossible. mb_detect_encoding's guess is probably as good as it gets :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide your tidy repairString call?

If you tried to use `input-encoding` and `output-encoding` from tidy options, try to not use these and use the third argument or `repairString` instead, something like this :

```
$oTidy = new tidy();
$page_content = $oTidy->repairString($page_content,
    array("show-errors" => 0, "show-warnings" => false),
    "utf8"
);
```

#### Edit :

After doing some tests, what I said before cannot work if you don't have utf8 encoding in `$page_content` already before calling `repairString`

But you will mostly end up with ISO-8859-1 (latin1) encoding if not UTF-8 already.

May I suggest you try :

```
$charset = mb_detect_encoding($amazon_description, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1');
if ($charset == "ISO-8859-1") {
    $amazon_description = utf8_encode($amazon_description);
}
$oTidy = new tidy();
$amazon_description = $oTidy->repairString($amazon_description,
    array("show-errors" => 0, "show-warnings" => false),
    "utf8"
);
```